# using __ngContext__ in a child component to access parent component

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs

In **angular 11**, I'm writing a template component, that takes in an **object config input**.
The config input includes an **array named fields**, which holds objects decribing form fields.
 On those objects I have **names of properties on the parent component** which I need as inputs for the form fields.
Since there are unknown elemnts of this nature (data arrays as inputs for form fields) I decided to include them in the configuration object that I input.
So the Config input looks something like this **(data property holde property name on parent)** :

```js
{
      formFields:[
        [
          {
            type: 'kendo-combobox',
            formfield:{
              className:"col-20",
              showErrors: "initial",
            },
            label:{
              isFloating: true,
              text: "claim type",
            },
            input:{
              type:"select",
              formControlName:"claimCode",
              valueField: 'claimCode',
              textField: 'claimType',
              valuePrimitive: true
              data:'claims'
            }
          },
          {
            type: 'app-adress',
            config:{
              entrance:{className:'col-5'},
              house:{className:'col-5'},
              street:{className:'col-20'}
            },
            data:'streets'
          }
        ]
      ],
      form:{
        group: this.form
      }
    }
```

The template HTML looks something like this:

```html
<form  [formGroup]="config.form?.group">
  <div class="row" *ngFor="let row of config?.formFields">
    <ng-container *ngFor="let field of row" >
      <ng-container [ngSwitch]="field.type">
        <ng-container  *ngSwitchCase="'kendo-combobox'">
          <kendo-formfield
          [attr.class]="field.formfield.className"
          [showErrors]="field.formfield?.showErrors || false">
            <kendo-floatinglabel [text]="field.label?.text || ''">
              <!--[data] holds the name for a data property on the parent-->
              <kendo-combobox
              [data]="field.data"
              [virtual]="{itemHeight: 28}"
              [textField]="field.textField"
              [valueField]="field.valueField"
              [formControlName]="'claimCode'"
              [valuePrimitive]="true">
              </kendo-combobox>
            </kendo-floatinglabel>
          </kendo-formfield>
        </ng-container>
        more switch cases. [data] holds the name ...
      </ng-container>
    </ng-container>
  </div>
</form>
```

****ngcontext****:
As I was debugging the ngOnInit method, I saw the ****ngcontext**** object on the component instance. This object holds an inheritence chain of sorts, of the the angular component tree, in the current compopnents context.
**The first elemnt in the **ngcontext** array is the parent component**, which holds the instance and its initial values.
Should I use this object, to refernce parent?
I not how can I reffernce the parent object, in a way that change detection will update the object, on my config input (I can pass in both a string of a data property, **but also** a referance to a data object on the parent component)?
I can use Inputs for this purpose.
possible ruled out solition:

- Injecting the parent directly is ruled out since the component need to be generic. exmaple:

  constructor(private _parent: ParentComponent)
- Using **parentInjector** is depracted
- Using **injector.get** also depracted

So how can I achieve this? an input object with referances to parent data object that updates on change detection. Should I use __ngContext__?
[![enter image description here][1]][1]